# AWS S3 bucket name being treated as a URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, dns, static-site

I am currently working through [the official walkthrough](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) to start hosting my site with AWS and I am stuck on **step 2.3**, setting up the www to root domain redirect.

Let's say I own the domain *abc.com*. I have created buckets called *abc.com* and *www.abc.com*. I activated the static website hosting flag on both buckets and I have uploaded my website files to the *abc.com* bucket as per instruction.

I then open the properties for the *www.abc.com* bucket, open the static website hosting panel and select the "Redirect requests" option. Apparently I can put a domain or bucket name in this field. I enter *abc.com*, the name of the bucket containing my site and accept.

Unfortunately the endpoint for my *www.abc.com* bucket does not redirect to my *abc.com* bucket-hosted site but the actual domain *abc.com* which currently is just being parked until I set up the nameservers with my registrar (I was planning on doing this at a later point).

Is this the expected behaviour? Why can't I redirect to my *abc.com* bucket as is? Will it not work until I set up my DNS records on Route 53? I realise there isn't much point in a www to root romain redirect until I've set up the custom domain anyway but it just seems weird that a bucket can't be redirected to if it shares a name with any existing website.

Comment: I've done some testing and it appears the redirect just does a 301 to whatever is put in the "Target bucket or domain" field, even if it isn't a valid domain name. I can't find any doco to back up that finding though, but there isn't anything that specifically saying a redirect to a bucket is possible or how it would work.